# My innerHTML is showing up BEFORE the div it should be writing to

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm currently writing some pretty basic code for a shopping cart on a webpage (it's for an assignment, and I'm restricted to JS, HTML and CSS)

I'm trying to fill in a table that fills with whatever is contained in a series of arrays (Name[], Quantity[] and Sum[]). I already have a  for the table, and the div I'm writing into is within a table. Yet whenever I run the webpage, the table and its contents are always written before my  as a seperate table.

I'm not entirely sure on what's gone wrong, so here's the code:
 HTML:

```
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>
           <th>Sum Total</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <div id="cart"></div>
        </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function ViewShoppingCart(){
        document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = ""; // Empties the cart

        for (var i=0; i<Name.length; i++) {
            var tr= document.createElement("tr");
            document.getElementById("cart").appendChild(tr);
            var td= document.createElement("td");
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Name[i]));
            tr.appendChild(td);
            var td1= document.createElement("td");
            td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Quantity[i])); 
            tr.appendChild(td1);
            var td2= document.createElement("td");
                    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\u00A3"+parseFloat(Sum[i]).toFixed(2))); 
            tr.appendChild(td2);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<div>` is not a valid child of `<table>`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-table-element.html#the-table-element) The browser is rearranging the DOM that represents your markup in an attempt to make sense of it.

If you want a div in a table, that div will have to be in a [`<th>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-th-element.html#the-th-element) or [`<td>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-td-element.html#the-td-element).

Answer (score 0):

your html is wrong. you cannot put a `<div>` inside a `<table>` tag. it needs to be inside `<td>` instead.